# file renaming not always caught by filenotify

Tags: dired, files

I'm using `file-notify-add-watch` from [filenotify.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/filenotify.el) to watch a dired directory so it can revert when a file is modified within the directory. This generally works, but I've noticed that it only works sometimes when renaming a file. Code is [here](https://github.com/cosmicexplorer/.emacs.d/blob/45ae1fbedd8424a48e3ae25937d4d1255a21ffa8/init-scripts/interface.el#L620).

When I watch two directories (`~/` and `~/readings`, for example) and add a file `test.txt` to `~/`, filenotify catches that and reverts the buffer. When I run `mv test.txt readings`, the event passed to the filenotify callback contains the sexp `'((<desc>) renamed "~/readings/test.txt" "~/readings/test.txt")`. When I move it back with `mv readings/test.txt .` (while in `~/`), the event passed to the callback is `'((<desc>) renamed "~/test.txt" "~/test.txt")`. So it seems to be passing not the previous and the new file, but just two of the new file's path. This could be a bug, but I'm not sure. For easier reading (`=>` indicates the events passed to the callback within emacs):

```
$ echo hey > test.txt
=> ((32) created "~/test.txt")
=> ((32) changed "~/test.txt")
$ mv test.txt readings
=> ((34) created "~/readings/test.txt")
$ mv readings/test.txt .
=> ((32) renamed "~/test.txt" "~/test.txt")
```

I'm pretty sure this is a bug, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't using filenotify incorrectly. Adding the watch, I do:

```
(file-notify-add-watch
  (expand-file-name dired-directory)
  '(change attribute-change) #'my-callback)
```

Which returns `32` and `34`, the two descriptors shown in the output above.

Is this a bug? Or is there some element of `file-notify-add-watch` I'm using incorrectly? I would expect `mv <file> <folder>` to create a `rename` notification with both the previous and current version, but it's not doing that. I'm using emacs 25.0.50 on linux with `'inotify` as a file notification library.

Comment: I will check further whether it is an error in filenotify.el, but as first comment: since (a recent git checkout of) Emacs 25.0.50 you could also apply `M-x auto-revert-mode` on your dired buffer.

Comment: I didn't know that! I have `global-auto-revert-mode` turned on; would that do the same thing, or is the local `auto-revert-mode` required? It doesn't seem to be auto-reverting (which would effectively do everything my code is supposed to do).

Comment: Huh, it does seem that the local `auto-revert-mode` is doing exactly that. I wonder why the global version doesn't do the same thing.

Comment: See the doc of global-auto-revert-mode:

`Global Auto Revert mode is a global minor mode that reverts any
buffer associated with a file when the file changes on disk.  Use
auto-revert-mode to revert a particular buffer.`

A dired buffer is not "associated with a file".

Comment: Oops, didn't catch that intricacy. If `auto-revert-mode` works, then I'll just use that instead of watching files manually; this behavior of filenotify is still strange though, I'll see if I can figure out what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem in renaming of files over directory boundaries. Should be fixed now in filenotify.el. Pls try a recent rebuild of Emacs 25.0.50.

Comment: Using the method I tried above, the newest build seems to work! I'll just file an actual bug next time; I didn't here cause I wasn't sure if I was using it correctly. Thanks so much.